# Adding the Transform video filter to ffmpeg

Tags: ubuntu, video, ffmpeg

first off I'm new to ffmpeg, and stackoverflow. so sorry If I'm doing something wrong.

Earlier I commented on a post related to this but it got deleted because it was not an answer or something. So I'm asking my own question here.

I followed this instructions https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

up untill Unzipping the ffmpeg file. Then I followed the facebook instructions

1. Checkout the source for ffmpeg
2. Copy vf_transform.c to the libavfilter subdirectory in ffmpeg source
3. Edit libavfilter/allfilters.c and register the filter by adding the line: REGISTER_FILTER(TRANSFORM, transform, vf); in the video filter registration section
4. Edit libavfilter/Makefile and add the filter to adding the line: OBJS-$(CONFIG_TRANSFORM_FILTER) += vf_transform.o in the filter section
5. Configure and build ffmpeg as usual

and finally I ran the remaining instructions from the compilation guide.

I did the whole process a couple times but The result is always the same when I try to test.

```
ffmpeg version N-80901-gfebc862 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
  configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libpulse --enable-libfreetype --enable-gnutls --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr --enable-libxvid --enable-libvidstab
  libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
  libavcodec     57. 48.101 / 57. 48.101
  libavformat    57. 41.100 / 57. 41.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
  libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Unknown filter 'transform'.
```

I'm on elementary OS.
Thx and sorry if the post is all wrong.

Comment: I repeated the process and had no problem. I guess you have run the wrong `ffmpeg` executable, which is provided by system or apt. Are you sure that `ffmpeg` you test is the one you build?

Comment: thank you. so I renamed the ffmpeg that was in the roots bin folder from the first time i installed ffmpeg. Then I did the whole process again but the bin folder in home was never created. so I have no way to launch it haha. if there is no bin folder where did it build to? shouldnt the process have created the folder? sorry I'm such a noob.

Comment: The `prefix` option indicates where ffmpeg bins are copied to if `make install` is executed. And the original build bins should be still in the source dir.

Comment: I made a centOS VM and it worked fine there. thanks for the help.